# Making Java WYSIWYG Editor - show styles via button styling not working?

Tags: java, swing

I am making a WYSIWYG editor from scratch in Java for learning purposes.  Right now I want to make it such that the user can tell what styling will be applied to the next typed character by which buttons are pressed/styled to indicate they are present but it is not working right now.

My current code for the JToolBar -

```
public class ToolBar extends JToolBar {
    private final JTextPane textPane;
    private final StyledEditorKit.BoldAction boldAction = new StyledEditorKit.BoldAction();
    private final StyledEditorKit.UnderlineAction underlineAction = new StyledEditorKit.UnderlineAction();
    private final StyledEditorKit.ItalicAction italicAction = new StyledEditorKit.ItalicAction();
    private JButton boldBtn;
    private JButton italicsBtn;
    private JButton  underlineBtn;
    private final Color defaultColor = new Color(238,238,238);
    private final Color selectedColor = new Color(100,100,100);
    public ToolBar(JTextPane textPane) {
        super("WYSIWYG Tools");
        this.textPane = textPane;
        setFloatable(false);
        setupButtons();
        updateButtonStates();
        textPane.addCaretListener(e -> updateButtonStates());
    }
    private void setupButtons() {
        boldBtn = createImageButton("src/resources/images/bold.png");
        boldBtn.addActionListener(this::boldStylize);
        italicsBtn = createImageButton("src/resources/images/italics.png");
        italicsBtn.addActionListener(this::italicStylize);
        underlineBtn = createImageButton("src/resources/images/underline.png");
        underlineBtn.addActionListener(this::underlineStylize);
        JButton strikeBtn = createImageButton("src/resources/images/strike.png");
        add(boldBtn);
        add(italicsBtn);
        add(underlineBtn);
        add(strikeBtn);
    }
    private static JButton createImageButton(String imagePath) {
        JButton button = new JButton();
        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath));
            button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return button;
    }
    private void boldStylize(ActionEvent e) {
        textPane.requestFocusInWindow();
        boldAction.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(textPane, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, null));
        updateButtonStates();
    }
    private void underlineStylize(ActionEvent e) {
        textPane.requestFocusInWindow();
        underlineAction.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(textPane, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, null));
        updateButtonStates();
    }
    private void italicStylize(ActionEvent e) {
        textPane.requestFocusInWindow();
        italicAction.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(textPane, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, null));
        updateButtonStates();
    }
    private void updateButtonStates() {
        System.out.println("updating button states");
        StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
        int caretPosition = textPane.getCaretPosition();
        System.out.println("Caret positions " + caretPosition);
        Element paragraphElement = doc.getParagraphElement(caretPosition);
        AttributeSet attrs = paragraphElement.getAttributes();
        //The above will tell us the current style of things
        boolean isBold = StyleConstants.isBold(attrs);
        boolean isItalics = StyleConstants.isItalic(attrs);
        boolean isUnderline = StyleConstants.isUnderline(attrs);
        System.out.println(String.format("bold %b italics %b underline %b", isBold, isItalics, isUnderline));
        if (isBold) {
            boldBtn.setBackground(selectedColor);
        } else {
            boldBtn.setBackground(defaultColor);
        }
        if (isItalics) {
            italicsBtn.setBackground(selectedColor);
        } else {
            italicsBtn.setBackground(defaultColor);
        }
        if (isUnderline) {
            underlineBtn.setBackground(selectedColor);
        } else {
            underlineBtn.setBackground(defaultColor);
        }
    }
}
```

I believe the problem is the first few lines of my `updateStateButtons` function the `attrs` always returns all my stylings back as false despite when typing in my TextPane I see stylings coming through.

I previously tried it as

```
        StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
        AttributeSet attrs = doc.getCharacterElement(textPane.getSelectionStart()).getAttributes();
```

And this sort of worked - if I highlighted a selection and applied bold, the bold button would be highlighted.  Then it would stay highlighted if I kept typing.  But if I went to the end of the text, it would unhighlight, but the next character I Would type is still bold.

I considered just manually toggling but I think it's possible that gets out of sync and it's just better to read the styling from the document but I am obviously not doing it completely correct.  Does anyone know how I can modify this so I can show the user what the next character will be styled as?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a `CaretListener` to check the current state of the attributes.

The `JTextPane` does have a `getInputAttributes()` method, which to me should be the method to use. However, it doesn't work for me. When the caret is positioned before the first stylized character it implies that the next character to be typed should be stylized, but it isn't.

So, the following code adjusts the caret position by 1 to get the attributes, which seems to give the correct result:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class TextPaneCaret
{
    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JButton bold = new JButton( new StyledEditorKit.BoldAction() );

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setText("Now is the time for...");
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( textPane );
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 200, 200 ) );

        textPane.addCaretListener((e) ->
        {
            StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
            int offset = textPane.getCaretPosition();

            if (offset > 0)
                offset--;

            Element characterElement = doc.getCharacterElement(offset);
            AttributeSet attributes = characterElement.getAttributes();

            System.out.println( attributes.containsAttribute(StyleConstants.Bold, Boolean.TRUE) );
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(bold, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
    }
}
```

Note: you may also need to check the current state when the button is clicked, since a CaretEvent will not be generated.